# Keeping Three Images (in a row) Responsive...when one image is larger than the other two

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, image-scaling

I've got a typical "media block selling points" row, with images on top and text below. Currently I'm using flexbox to keep everything orderly, but I'll create a fallback (probably table-cells or inline-block) eventually. That's not the issue (in fact, flexbox is AMAZING).

An example: http://drwoe.nl/

My problem is this: two of the images are the same width and height. Imagine circles with an illustrated character inside them. The third image has a circle of the same height and width, but the illustrated character "breaks out of" the circle, making the image larger.

I have given the first two images the responsive treatment, and they resize together nicely. To get the third one to render as the designer wanted, I have to specify a min-width (at least) to allow it to match the circles' sizes. Does this make sense?

If I didn't have to make these images resize nicely, this wouldn't be an issue. But I can't figure out how to keep the third image, which is technically larger than the two (due to the "breakout" illustration) resize with them.

I do have the PSD of the design and can pull out pieces that I need. I have tried creating CSS3 circles and adding the illustration in a pseudo element (positioning absolutely), but I couldn't get them to resize together.

Is this a genuine brain teaser or am I missing something simple? Thanks very much!

Comment: it would be great to have some code or even better, a js fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) that describes your issue

Comment: Sorry, chadocat. Here's an example:

http://codepen.io/matthewbivins/pen/Ckcme

Comment: So, here's a temporary solution to the issue above that I came up with: 

I sliced the images as .jpegs with the same width and height, based on the size of the last image (the one that was larger). It felt a little dirty, but it works, at least. I'd still like to know if there is a better way out there!

Answer (score 0):

The third image is bigger than the other two, that means you either make the image the same sizes and resize normally or have a smaller min-widht (for example min-width:136px).

The other option would be to make the cirlces in complete css and have the images inside the cicle with overflow:hidden. This will cut of some of the wings though. Looks like you just need a smaller image